# Dynamically creating new tag in main window of core-drawer-panel

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design

I have the following drawer-form component

drawer-form.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/paper_elements/paper_icon_button.html">
<polymer-element name='drawer-form'>
  <template>
    <section id='reg' layout horizontal center>
      <paper-icon-button
        icon="menu"
        id='menu_icon'
        on-click='{{clickHandler}}'>
      </paper-icon-button>
      <h4 id='regLbl'>New Patient</h4>
    </section>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'dart:html';

    @CustomTag( 'drawer-form' )
    class DrawerForm extends PolymerElement {
      @observable bool state = false;

      DrawerForm.created() : super.created();

      void clickHandler( ) {
        fire( 'CREATE_NEW_PATIENT' );
      }
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The drawer-form is used in a main-form component:

main-form.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_drawer_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_icon_button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/paper_elements/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/paper_elements/paper_icon_button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/fontawesome_elements/fontawesome_icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="drawer-form.html">

<polymer-element name="main-form">
  <template>
    <core-drawer-panel id="core_drawer_panel">
      <section id="drawer" drawer>
        <drawer-form></drawer-form>
      </section>

      <section id="main" main>
        <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar">
          <paper-icon-button
            icon="menu"
            id='menu_icon'
            on-click='{{menu_icon_handler}}'>
          </paper-icon-button>
          <div id="div" flex>Toolbar</div>
        </core-toolbar>

        <section id='content'></section>
      </section>
    </core-drawer-panel>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'dart:html';

    import 'package:core_elements/core_drawer_panel.dart';

    @CustomTag( 'main-form' )
    class MainForm extends PolymerElement {
      CoreDrawerPanel drawerPanel;

      MainForm.created() : super.created();

      void toggleDrawer() {
        bool state = drawerPanel.narrow;
      }

      void menu_icon_handler() {
        bool state =  drawerPanel.narrow;
        print ( state );
      }

      @override
      void attached() {
         super.attached();
         drawerPanel = $['drawerPanel']  as CoreDrawerPanel;
      }
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The clickHandloer in drawer-form.html fires a 'CREATE_NEW_PATIENT' event. How do I capture this event in the main-form component to dyanmically create the new-patient?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could strip your code from all parts that are not necessary to reproduce your problem (emptly lines, style tags, tags that are not necessary to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use lowercase characters and dash for the event name (I very recently saw a bug report that this doesn't work).

I don't think anybody is able to catch an event fired from an element not yet attached to the DOM.
The constructor is therefore a bad place to put your 'fire' code to, use `attached()` (after `super.attached()`) instead.

Then you can listen in code like

// main-form

```dart
@override
void attached() {
  super.attached();
  this.shadowRoot.querySelector('drawer-form').on['create-new-patient'].listen((e) {
    print('create-new-patient received');
  }  
}
```

or declaratively

```dart
<drawer-form on-create-new-patient='{{myEventHandlerInMainForm}}'>
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter. But the element is attached to the DOM. The event is fired via a clickHandler after the DOM is constructed in drawer-form, NOT from the constructor as you are stating. The event MUST be fired when the button in drawer-form is clicked NOT when the the element is attached.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I think that was before I fixed the formatting. I somehow misinterpreted your code.